# Security suggestions for first-time chrome extension developer

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a google chrome extension that stores the active url, date time and user's text input when the user submits that text input (there are no user logins). Optionally, I could also use the activetabs permission for some non-essential additional functionality (toggling the visibility of the extension's on-screen icon).

Goole now wants me to write a privacy policy before they'll publish it (they won't tell me why), and I'm concerned that being a front-end developer, I have overlooked something essential on the back-end (I have assumed that the webhost who stores/serves the data handles authentication, and have nothing in my php for authorisation).

I have looked online but found nothing to assuage my fears regarding the security vulnerabilities of my extension, and how safe (free from litigation) it would be to publish it as an individual (without the legal protection of a company); I don't store any user data that could identify a user, but I'm unsure if my extension nonetheless has access to that data and if I need to install security measures to ensure that a malicious third-party couldn't make off with it.

Any help, suggested direction would be greatly appreciated - I'm at a bit of a loose end and may not publish the extension without greater confidence.

Comment: This is essentially a legal question, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The privacy policy compliance is a legal issue.  Check out the GDPR for more info on that.

Comment: Ah, OK - so on the surface of it, your replies suggest to me that given the function of my extension I shouldn't be unconcerned with the legality of it, which is helpful - thank you. I'm checking out the GDPR now. I guess most developers on stackoverflow work from the legal protection of companies(/non-individual entities)/know these questions are outside its scope.